# How to Dispose object created in a method of a class in C#

Tags: c#

I have a class in which I write several methods. I declare some objects in that class and `Dispose` them in a `catch` block. When I tried to apply `Ruleset` on it, it gives warning message of CA2000. My Code is as follow

```
 public int ValidationExcelBal(string excelPath, string objectReferenceExcelPath)
        {
            DataTable dtPointList = new DataTable();
            DataTable dtAlarm = new DataTable();
            DataTable dtObjectReference = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                int objectReferenceColNum = -1;
                int objectReferenceAlarmColNum = -1;


                objGGTAutoBindingToolDal.YomitoriExcelToDataTable(excelPath, ref dtPointList, ref dtAlarm);
                objGGTAutoBindingToolDal.ObjectReferenceExcelToData(objectReferenceExcelPath, ref dtObjectReference);

                #region code to find object reference column number in excel sheet and Alarm sheet


                for (int i = 0; i < dtPointList.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < dtPointList.Rows.Count; k++)
                    {
                        if (k < 4)
                        {
                            string name = dtPointList.Rows[k][i].ToString().Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "");
                            if (name == "ObjectReference")
                            {
                                objectReferenceColNum = i;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //code to find colomn number of object reference field in Alarm sheet
                for (int j = 0; j < dtAlarm.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    string name = dtAlarm.Rows[0][j].ToString();
                    if (name.Equals("Object Reference"))
                    {
                        objectReferenceAlarmColNum = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                #endregion

                if (objectReferenceColNum == -1 || objectReferenceAlarmColNum == -1)
                {
                    return 1;
                }

                //if (Convert.ToString(dtObjectReference.Columns[0]).Contains("Bldg Name") || Convert.ToString(dtObjectReference.Columns[1]).Contains("Graphics Name") || Convert.ToString(dtObjectReference.Columns[2]).Contains("Controller Object Reference"))
                //{

                //    return 2;
                //}

                return 3;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dtPointList.Dispose();
                dtAlarm.Dispose();
                dtObjectReference.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }
```

and my warning is as follow

```
Warning 17  CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'GgtAutoBindingToolBal.ValidationExcelBal(string, string)', call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'dtPointList' before all references to it are out of scope.    D:\Project\Pragati Installer\GGTAutoBindingBll\GgtAutoBindingToolBal.cs 26  GgtAutoBindingBll
```

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do is to replace the manual call to `Dispose()` with a `using` statement (will call `Dispose()` when running out of scope).

```
using (DataTable dtPointList = new DataTable()) {
   ...
}
```

Example:

```
using (DataTable dtPointList = new DataTable()) {
    using (DataTable dtAlarm = new DataTable()) {
        using (DataTable dtObjectReference = new DataTable()) {
            // your code here, no need to call Dispose() on any of these objects
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To be able to do this, you need to implement IDisposable Interface on your class and dispose the objects inside the Dispose() Method.

Comment: Dispose is for unmanaged resources, like file handles and database
connections. The rule of thumb is to call Dispose on any and every
object that implements IDisposable.

Comment: I didn't get what you want to say can you please give an example.

Answer (score 0):

You call dispose only in the catch block. What if there is no exception in try block? Shouldn't it be disposed there as well? Try it and see if the warning meessage i still there. As it was mentioned in the other answer - using is your best option. This way the resource will be used in the scope of the using code block.

```
public int ValidationExcelBal(string excelPath, string objectReferenceExcelPath)
{
    using (DataTable dtPointList = new DataTable())
    {
        using (DataTable dtAlarm = new DataTable())
        {
            using (DataTable dtObjectReference = new DataTable())
            {
                try
                {
                    int objectReferenceColNum = -1;
                    int objectReferenceAlarmColNum = -1;


                    objGGTAutoBindingToolDal.YomitoriExcelToDataTable(excelPath, ref dtPointList, ref dtAlarm);
                    objGGTAutoBindingToolDal.ObjectReferenceExcelToData(objectReferenceExcelPath, ref dtObjectReference);

                    #region code to find object reference column number in excel sheet and Alarm sheet


                    for (int i = 0; i < dtPointList.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < dtPointList.Rows.Count; k++)
                        {
                            if (k < 4)
                            {
                                string name = dtPointList.Rows[k][i].ToString().Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "");
                                if (name == "ObjectReference")
                                {
                                    objectReferenceColNum = i;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //code to find colomn number of object reference field in Alarm sheet
                    for (int j = 0; j < dtAlarm.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        string name = dtAlarm.Rows[0][j].ToString();
                        if (name.Equals("Object Reference"))
                        {
                            objectReferenceAlarmColNum = j;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    #endregion

                    if (objectReferenceColNum == -1 || objectReferenceAlarmColNum == -1)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    //if (Convert.ToString(dtObjectReference.Columns[0]).Contains("Bldg Name") || Convert.ToString(dtObjectReference.Columns[1]).Contains("Graphics Name") || Convert.ToString(dtObjectReference.Columns[2]).Contains("Controller Object Reference"))
                    //{

                    //    return 2;
                    //}

                    return 3;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    dtPointList.Dispose();
                    dtAlarm.Dispose();
                    dtObjectReference.Dispose();
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to dispose it in try block but still its giving same error message.

Comment: I tried this but its giving error when trying to pass Data Table ref to method because it is using variable.

Comment: Can you please update your question then to reflect that case? I dont see the DataTable parameter in your current method.

Comment: Its there after int objectReferenceAlarmColNum = -1; where i pass that Data Table as a ref to a method.